Terraform EKS node groups not passing user data to launch template and eks nodes
Will appreciate any solutions or recommendations for this issue.
Dependencies

K8s: 1.29
ami: amazon-eks-node-1.29-v20240615
Terraform: v1.8.4
Cloud: AWS Service: EKS

Context
I am currently using Terraform to set up my EKS cluster . We were noticing issues at the place I work when pods in the EKS managed node groups were over utilising resources and stalling kubelet and other system critical resources. The solution was to add restrictions on max_pods , kube-reserved and system-reserved params on the EKS node so that these reservations were respected before allocating pods .
Path to the Solution
The way to do this is to run the bootstrap.sh script on the EKS node at startup to override the defaults
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${cluster_name} \
    --kubelet-extra-args "--max-pods=40 --system-reserved cpu=500m,memory=500Mi,ephemeral-storage=1Gi --kube-reserved cpu=1000m,memory=1024Mi,ephemeral-storage=3Gi"

As I am doing this on terraform I need to find a way to inject this shell script into the EKS launch template which will thereby pass it through to the ec2-user-data which will execute at the EKS node startup . I have also tested this bash script by manually running it on the EKS node and restarting with systemctl restart kubelet  it worked without a problem the nodes reacted as expected by limiting pods and allocatable resources .
Problem
My problem is that my current terraform script along with template file are not making it to the launch template user-data-script and hence the ec2 user script therefore not applying it to the eke-managed-nodes at launch .
A few ways I tried and confirmed this .

verifying the launch template created by eks for the node-groups showed no indication of my script
also by checking eks node cloud_init logs like this
vi /var/log/cloud-init.log (and) vi /var/log/cloud-init-output.log) and looking for my commands they were no where to be seen
ps aux | grep kubelet
vi /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json
k get nodes node_name -o json | grep -i allocatable -A 15 , clearly pointed to the fact that my reservations dint take effect

  "allocatable": {
            "cpu": "7910m",     # Should have been 6500,because cpu reservation was 500+1000
            "ephemeral-storage": "95551679124",
            "hugepages-1Gi": "0",
            "hugepages-2Mi": "0",
            "memory": "31295956Ki",
            "pods": "58"
        },
        "capacity": {
            "cpu": "8",
            "ephemeral-storage": "104845292Ki",
            "hugepages-1Gi": "0",
            "hugepages-2Mi": "0",
            "memory": "32312788Ki",
            "pods": "58"
        },

Code
Terraform to set up EKS
Only keeping the bits I think can help in debugging.
module "eks" {
  ................
  ................
  ................
  ................
  ................
  # EKS Managed Node Group(s)
  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    instance_types = ["m6i.large", "m5.large", "m5n.large", "m5zn.large"]
    disk_size      = 100
  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    eks-ng1 = {
      min_size                   = 2
      max_size                   = 12
      desired_size               = 2
      instance_types             = ["m6i.2xlarge", "m7i.2xlarge", "m6a.2xlarge", "c6i.2xlarge"]
      capacity_type              = "SPOT"
      use_custom_launch_template = false
      create_launch_template = false
      disk_size                  = 100
      labels = {
        "node-managed-by" = "eks-ng1"
      }

      iam_role_additional_policies = {
        AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore"
      }

      ami_id = "ami-xxxxxxxxxx" # hidden
      enable_bootstrap_user_data = true
      pre_bootstrap_user_data = templatefile("templates/bootstrap.sh.tpl", {
         cluster_name = local.cluster_name
       })

      post_bootstrap_user_data = templatefile("templates/bootstrap.sh.tpl", {
        cluster_name = local.cluster_name
      })
    }
  }

  tags = {
      "karpenter.sh/discovery" = local.cluster_name
    }

}

Bootstrap script
#!/bin/bash
set -xe
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${cluster_name} \
    --kubelet-extra-args "--max-pods=40 --system-reserved cpu=500m,memory=500Mi,ephemeral-storage=1Gi --kube-reserved cpu=1000m,memory=1024Mi,ephemeral-storage=3Gi"

My attempt was to try and inject my bootstrap script into the launch template user data , but it was not working with my approach .
References used to put together a solution -  No luck yet .
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/1770#issuecomment-1227047342
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/16f46db94b7158fd762d9133119206aaa7cf6d63/modules/eks-managed-node-group/variables.tf#L53
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/2059

Based on the module code, the settings you are trying are added either in the eks_managed_node_group_defaults variable or in the self_managed_node_group_defaults variable.

You can also read this rePost article to understand when the user data scripts run.
